# Переопределить функцию в системе автоматической обрезки изображений

Tags: wordpress, crop

Возможно ли переопределить функцию wp_crop_image в системе автоматической обрезки изображений на Wordpress? Мне необходимо самому обрезать эти изображения по заданным мною параметрам. Если это возможно то каким образом?.

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании значит `переопределить` и `самому обрезать изображения по заданным мною параметрам`? Чем не подходит `add_image_size()`? И какую проблему Вы пытаетесь этим решить?

Comment: Будет использоваться внешний сервис с распознаванием лица, сервис принимает изображение и передает массив с координатами лица: стартовые точки по x,y, длину и ширину обрезки. это те параметры, которые может принимать функция wp_crop_image, и по которым она может обрезать так, как мне нужно. Проблема add_image_size в том, что эта функция может принимать третьим параметром массив для обрезки, но он строго ограничен такими параметрами: x_crop_position accepts: 'left', 'center', or 'right'.
y_crop_position accepts: 'top', 'center', or 'bottom', но никак не координаты пикселей на изображении.

Comment: Переопределить - переписать её функционал под себя, возможно ли такое вмешательство в ядро WP?

Comment: "Переписать её функционал под себя, возможно ли такое вмешательство в ядро WP?", -- Нет конечно же.

Comment: После загрузки изображения в медиа, система автоматической обрезки делает несколько вариантов обрезки изначального изображения, не могли бы подсказать какой хук я мог бы использовать, чтобы втиснуться после загрузки изображения и сделать нужный мне  вариант обрезки?

Comment: Если вдруг кому будет нужно, мне помог экшн — add_attachment